# Oracle 11g on centos 7 ldconfig issue

Tags: oracle, centos, centos7, freeze

After installing oracle 11g and adding its libraries to /etc/ld.so.conf.d I've run into

`dbus-daemon: /usr/bin/dbus-daemon: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/dbus-daemon: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt`

and the system locked out.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing libexpat.so* from oracle libraries.

Comment: Oracle is not and never has been certified for centos.  Oracle 11.2.0.4 only has a year of extended support left, and < 11.2.0.4 is completely out of support.  So one has to wonder why you are attempting such an installation.